# Qué versión de Yolo recomiendan para hacer detección de objetos en dispositivos con pocos recursos

Tags: python, opencv, inteligencia-artificial, yolo

mi consulta básicamente es qué versión de Yolo me recomiendan para detectar objetos en múltiples cámaras a la vez (12 al menos) con un dispositivo que no tenga demasiados recursos. He visto que se puede utilizar algunas versiones tiny de Yolo, pero no he podido terminar de configurar o entrenar una, mi consulta es más que nada para ver si alguien me puede sugerir una versión que sea buena para lo que necesito y si me puede compartir alguna guía o algún documento que yo pueda utilizar de guía.

Muchas gracias desde ya!

Comment: La versión más eficiente para tu propósito podría ser YOLOv3. De todas formas, mira [este enlace](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) que contiene información e imágenes que te serán útiles y de gran ayuda. Para la guía tienes este [otro enlace](https://www.aprendemachinelearning.com/modelos-de-deteccion-de-objetos/) que explica en que consiste y como se hace para detectar y localizar objetos

Comment: @DanielSánchez muchas gracias, cómo me recomendarías entrenar un modelo para YOLOv3 o v4? he estado intentando a través de google colab pero me da ciertos problemas para esas versiones antiguas de YOLO porque al parecer colab se actualiza de versión de cuda y deja de funcionar todo. Hablo de los scripts que están predefinidos para entrenar modelos en colab, hay varios.